# Automatically Begin Upload ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Without using a third-party control, is it possible to automatically begin uploading a file as soon as the user selects a file and the file browser window closes? I have the data struture in place as well as all the information needed to capture the data, but I need a way of knowing if the file upload has changed? Is there an event that fires, or something I can capture to achieve this?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>No.  Not without using a third-party control.</s>

It looks like it is possible using a hidden `<IFRAME>`.  Check out the [AJAX File Uploader](http://seemysites.net/projFolder/uploader/).

There are simple [Silverlight](http://silverlightuploader.codeplex.com/) and [Flash](http://www.element-it.com/multiple-file-upload/flash-uploader.aspx) solutions available as well, however.